# Connected Set that is Clopen is a Component

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> If $\emptyset \neq K \subseteq X$ is connected and clopen, then $K$ is a component.

I'm not entirely sure this is true, so hopefully someone will correct me. Here is an incomplete attempt at a proof. Since $K$ is connected, it must be contained in exactly one component $C$. Note that $C = K \cup (C-K)$. I want to argue that this is a separation and therefore disconnects $C$, which is a contradiction unless $C-K= \emptyset$. Note that $\overline{K} \cap (C-K) = K \cap (C-K) = \emptyset$. All I need to show is that $K \cap \overline{(C-K)} = \emptyset$ to conclude these sets disconnect $C$, but for some reason the proof is eluding me. I could use a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $K$ and $C-K$ separate $C$, you can show they are both open in $C$, have union $C$ and are disjoint. Disjointness is easy, and it is also clear that they have union $C$. So, you need to show $K$ is clopen inside $C$. Hint: What is the subspace topology?